# Выравнивание строк относительно друг друга внутри соседних ячеек grid на чистом CSS

Tags: css, grid

Никак не получается в dislay: grid контейнере в ячейках выровнять авторов в серых блоках так, чтобы они были относительно авторов из соседних блоков на одном уровне. Т.е. как бы не увеличивался заголовок, становясь по высоте больше заголовков в соседних ячейках - авторы всегда находятся на одном уровне относительно друг друга - получается, выравниваясь относительно первого автора в ячейке с самым большим по высоте заголовком. Т.е. если глянуть на код (развернуть на весь экран), то авторы в ячейках 6 и 8 должны выстроиться на один уровень с авторами ячейки 7, а у 2 - на уровень авторов ячейки 3

```css
.section_arts
{
display: grid;
width: 100%;
max-width: 1600px;
margin: 0 auto;
grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
gap: 32px;
}

.section_arts > .card
{
background: gray;
}

.section_arts > .card:first-of-type 
{
grid-column: 1 / span 2;
grid-row: 1 / span 2;
width: 784px;
height: auto;
position: relative;
}

.section_arts > .card:nth-of-type(5) 
{
width: auto;
background: #dc2828;
grid-column: 4;
grid-row: 2 / span 2;
}

a 
{
display: block
}
```

```html
<div class="section_arts">
<div class="card">
<h3>Заголовок 1</h3>
<div>
<a href="">Иван Петров</a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="card">
<h3>Заголовок 2</h3>
<div>
<a href="">Иван Петров</a>
<a href="">Иван Иванов</a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="card">
<h3>Заголовок 3<br>3<br>3<br>3<br>3<br>3<br></h3>
<div>
<a href="">Иван Петров</a>
<a href="">Иван Иванов</a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="card">
<h3>Заголовок 4</h3>
<div>
<a href="">Иван Петров</a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="card">
<h3>Заголовок 5<br>5<br>5<br>5<br>5<br>5<br>5<br></h3>
<div>
<a href="">Иван Петров</a>
<a href="">Иван Иванов</a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="card">
<h3>Заголовок 6</h3>
<div>
<a href="">Иван Петров</a>
<a href="">Иван Иванов</a>
<a href="">Иван Петров</a>
<a href="">Иван Иванов</a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="card">
<h3>Заголовок 7<br>7<br>7<br>7<br>7<br>7<br></h3>
<div>
<a href="">Иван Петров</a>
<a href="">Иван Иванов</a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="card">
<h3>Заголовок 8</h3>
<div>
<a href="">Иван Петров</a>
<a href="">Иван Иванов</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Если все динамично - то на css нет возможности это сделать. Применяйте JS.

Comment: Да, я так и не нашёл решение. Видимо только джс